# Customer is not created on stripe account

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am running this node.js code to create customer on stripe account function deploy successful but failed to create customer on stripe I am not getting what I am missing.
Fire base functions folder is also not showing the function there.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    const stripe = require('stripe')("secret key here");
    var customer;

    stripe.customers.create(
      {
        email: 'customer@example.com',
      },
      {
        maxNetworkRetries: 2, 
      }
    );
```

Comment: Can you show the error that you're getting?

Comment: actually I am not getting any error it deploy successfully but this code should create customer on my stripe account which is not generating

Comment: the only way to check what's going on, is checking the response from the call. So check the response, and put here the message, so we can help you. `.then/.catch` or `async/await` and asign it to a variable

Comment: I need to ask should it create a function on functions tab in fire base? if yes than this code is not even generating function there.

Answer (score 3):

When you use APIs to services (viz. stripe.com and firebase) outside your complete control, you must check for errors. If you're using a service incorrectly the error will explain, or at least hint, what you're doing wrong.

The [stripe-node API documentation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) suggests you invoke stripe.customer.create() as an awaited function, like this:

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
         email: 'customer@example.com',
});
```

This is easy if you call it from an async function. You should use this sort of code in your async function to check for errors back from stripe.com.

```
try {
   const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
         email: 'customer@example.com',
    });
    /* here's your customer object */
}
catch (error) {
    console.error ('stripe', error);
}
```

If you do not call it from an async function, you can wait for results using the Promises scheme.

```
    stripe.customers.create({
         email: 'customer@example.com',
       })
    .then ( function (customer) {
             /* here's your customer object */
       })
    .catch ( function (error) {
        console.error ('stripe', error);
       });
```

If you haven't yet figured out how async/await or Promises work, the time has come for you do to that.

Comment: I am following the stripe documentation which you mentioned here but I found an error  while using await and the error is await can only use with async. I am very new with js

Comment: firebaseconifq and gcloud_project environment variables are missing initializing firebase-admin will fail
finding this error when I run node index.js in cmd